# Neo4j merge nodes by shared node property

Tags: neo4j

Can anyone help me on how can I do something similar to SQL's self-join in Neo4j?

```
 MATCH (z:Z {id: "415a404a100ccccccccccccc"})<-[:INCLUDES]-(n)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(s:S)
 WHERE n:X OR n:Y
 RETURN ?? —> Here I want to do self-join based on s id (S id) and merge properties from all nodes
```

S is shop.

Every shop can create two type of region X and Y.

In both region I have the following node properties,

shopId
minBasketSize  Every region has a relation with city (z in this case).

With the query that I’ve shared, for example: I can get 3 nodes, including all regions. However, I only want to return 2 nodes, since two different type of region share the same shopId.

**Update:**

n -> includes z => where n is two available label types x, y

x -> belongs_to s => where x keeps s_id and some other properties such as minBasketSizeX

y -> belong_to y => where y also keep s_id and some other properties such as minBasketSizeY

Now the question is, from given z, how can you return data like the following:

s1 => { minBasketSizeX: 30, minBasketSizeY: 20 }
s2 => { minBasketSizeX: null (if there's no y node for that given z, minBasketSizeY: 20 }

Comment: With your WHERE clause, you will only get paths back where n is an :X or a :Y type node. Doesn't this get you your two desired nodes? What do you want to do with them? You can collect() them into a list grouping by `s` (so each shop only has one row, with its list of regions), or collect just interested data into a list per shop, or you can sum some of their properties or do something else. More details please.

Comment: Still some confusion...you said that :Y nodes have a `:BELONGS_TO` relationship to another :Y node? Is it in addition labeled as an :S Shop node, because your pattern only works if :BELONGS_TO relationships point to :S nodes. If you want this to allow patterns where `(:Y)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(:Y)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(:S)` (or longer patterns), then we need to know if this is what you want, and if :S and :Y labels can be on the same node or not. With that info you can probably develop such a query using variable-length patterns and some extra logic.